# How would you subscribe to specific stream using ActionCable

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, actioncable

I have a native rails web app and an iOS app that has a chat component. I'm using ActionCable to provide real-time messaging.

The server broadcasts to two streams in MessageChannel when the message is created in the MessageController

- rendered html to go to the web chat
- json object to go to the iOS app

Can you create a stream specific subscription? That is, on the client side, can you filter the html broadcast from the json broadcast?

Or should I create an ApiMessageChannel and a web MessageChannel? This feels like unnecessary duplication because the create will always broadcast to both web and api.

***MessageChannel***

```rb
class MessageChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for Group.find(params["id"])
    stream_from "message:messages_api_#{params["id"]}"
  end
end
```

***MessageController***

```rb
def create
# ... 

MessageChannel.broadcast_to group, message: render_to_string(message, locals: { previous_message: previous_message, type: group.type, current_user: current_user })

MessageChannel.broadcast_to "messages_api_#{group.id}", message: ApplicationController.render_with_signed_in_user(current_user, json: { sender: current_user.username, content: message.body })
end
```

***ChatRoom Controller***

```js
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "messages", "newMessage" ]

  connect() {
    this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "MessageChannel", id: this.data.get("id") }, {
      connected: this._connected.bind(this),
      disconnected: this._disconnected.bind(this),
      received: this._received.bind(this)
    })
  }

  disconnect() {
    consumer.subscriptions.remove(this.subscription)
  }

  _connected() {
  }

  _disconnected() {
  }

  _received(data) {
    if (data.message) {
      this.messagesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.message);
      $('.js-chat-messages').scrollTop($('.js-chat-messages')[0].scrollHeight);
    }
  }

  clearMessage(event) {
    this.newMessageTarget.value = ''
  }
}
```

***Swift iOS***

````swift
static var ChannelIdentifier = "MessageChannel"
    let actionCableClient = ActionCableClient(url: URL(string: "wss://localhost:3000/cable")!)

        actionCableClient.headers = [
            "Authorization": token,
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        
        actionCableClient.connect()

        let room_identifier = ["id" : "12"]
        actionCableChannel = actionCableClient.create(ActionCableController.ChannelIdentifier, parameters: room_identifier, autoSubscribe: true, bufferActions: true )

actionCableChannel?.onReceive = { (data: Any?, error: Error?) in
            print("recieved message!")
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR: Unable to receive message from ActionCable Channel: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To subscribe to a specific named stream you can:

```rb
class MessageChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "message:messages_web"
    # stream_from "message:messages_api"
    # stream_from "message:messages_test"

    stream_from "message:messages_#{params[:type]}"

    # !! can also add in other parameters and add those on the client side for stream specific filtering
    # stream_from "message:messages_#{params[:type]}_#{params[:id]}"

  end
end
```

```rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    MessageChannel.broadcast_to "messages_web", 'web'
    MessageChannel.broadcast_to "messages_api", 'api'
    MessageChannel.broadcast_to "messages_test", 'test'
  end
end
```

```js
import consumer from "channels/consumer"
this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "MessageChannel", type: 'web'}, {
  connected: this._connected.bind(this),
  disconnected: this._disconnected.bind(this),
  received: this._received.bind(this)
})
```

This will only receive messages from "message:messages_web"

Answer (score -1):

Based on the doc, you can know as below:

> found out that the subscribed method is called via client-side javascript, not by the rails controller.

based on your question, you should subscribe to special resources, right?

Comment: What do you mean special resources? Is there a way to filter the stream on the client side? Is there a way to subscribe without creating 2 separate channels?